# How can I make this sophistictaed?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I'm trying to change this pagination to reverse pagination. from

```
|Last|Next|25|24|23|22|21|Previous|First|
```

to

```
|First|Previous|21|22|23|24|25|Next|Last|
```

So, I coded like this below, but it takes so long. It's probably because it fetches all the comments in order to pass argument first, and then it does again in `application_controller.rb`

Is there any smart way to make this faster?

**user_controller.rb**

```
@comments = reverse_paginate(Comment.where(:user_id => user_ids, :commentable_type => commentable).order('created_at DESC'), params[:page])
```

**application_controller.rb**

```
def reverse_paginate(scope, page)
    if page
        page_number = page
    else 
        page_number = Kaminari.paginate_array(scope.reverse).page(1).per(10).num_pages
    end
    Kaminari.paginate_array(scope.reverse).page(page_number).per(10).reverse!
end
```

Comment: You reverse your array twice in last line in application_controller. Is it necessary?

Comment: 1(Old), 2, 3....10, 11, 12(Newer) But in the same page, I want the newest one on the top and the oldest comment on the bottom. That's how I want the record ordered

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you'll have to override the paginator template of Kaminari.

```
<%= paginator.render do -%>
  <nav class="pagination">
    <%= first_page_tag unless current_page.first? %>
    <%= prev_page_tag unless current_page.first? %>
    <% each_page do |page| -%>
      <% if page.left_outer? || page.right_outer? || page.inside_window? -%>
        <%= page_tag page %>
      <% elsif !page.was_truncated? -%>
        <%= gap_tag %>
      <% end -%>
    <% end -%>
    <%= next_page_tag unless current_page.last? %>
    <%= last_page_tag unless current_page.last? %>
  </nav>
<% end -%>
```

Source [here](https://github.com/amatsuda/kaminari/blob/master/app/views/kaminari/_paginator.html.erb)